# simple dynamic allocation question

Tags: c++

What is the difference between this:-

```
width = new int;
```

And this:-

```
int width;
```

i.e. of what use is the dynamic allocation in the first code?

Comment: You probably want to change "width = new int;" to "int* width = new int;" :)

Comment: You should probably sit down with a begginer c++ book as you clearly are missing the fundamentals of pointers

Answer (score 3):

The former allocates dynamically one `int` and returns its address in memory (which is written to the variable `width` and you have to free it later with `delete`. It exists until then.

The latter declares a local variable of type `int` which becomes invalid when it leaves the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

What you meant is probably:

```
int* w1 = new int;
int  w2;
```

The first is allocated on the heap and you have to take care of thememory with operator `delete`.

The second is on the stack and ceases to exist after it gets out of the scope (so you do not have to take care of the memory yourself).

Comment: Technically, the first is allocated on the 'free store'. Also, when not dealing with built-in types, there's a difference between the `delete` operator and `operator delete` -- if you allocate and construct a new T using the `new` operator, you must destruct and deallocate the T using the `delete` operator. The `operator delete` function is what handles the deallocation of the memory -- but it's a mistake to do e.g. `T *p = new T; ::operator delete(p);', because T's destructor won't be called.

Comment: And as far as standard C++ is concerned, there doesn't actually have to be a 'stack' IIRC -- although that's how all the usual implementations work.

Answer (score 0):

one is allocated on the heap and the other on the stack, one you have to manage and the other is "automatic", one you access via a de-reference the other you don't...

EDIT: with respect to your second question, not much... there are a few cases, but then you'd almost always use a smart pointer, if not, you're playing with fire... :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one allocates space for the integer on heap and allocates space to hold the pointer on stack. It also initializes width to 0. Space allocated on heap has to be de-allocated by the programmer (extra burden). This space on heap can be accessed from anywhere as long as pointer to it is available and the memory is not freed.

Second declaration just allocates space on stack and is freed automatically when the variable goes out of scope. The value of width is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

It's very rare that dynamic allocation of *one* `int` would be "of use," though I wouldn't say "never."

Dynamic allocation is useful for large, complicated data structures whose lifetime and/or size is not known at compile time, or that are just plain too big to put on the stack.